# Decrypting substitution cipher in Python yields correct substitutions for some letters, but not others

Tags: python, cryptography

To help me learn Python, I have been working on a small script to decrypt a simple substitution cipher on Python Challenge. If you wish to avoid potential spoilers, please stop here.

The ciphertext is rotated back two steps and the ciphertext input is as follows:

```
thread = "g fmnc wms bgblr rpylqjyrc gr zw fylb. rfyrq ufyr amknsrcpq ypc dmp. bmgle gr gl zw fylb gq glcddgagclr ylb rfyr'q ufw rfgq rcvr gq qm jmle. sqgle qrpgle.kyicrpylq() gq pcamkkclbcb. lmu ynnjw ml rfc spj."
```

The script that I used is as follows, with comments.

```
cipher = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

for letter in thread:
  if letter in cipher and cipher.index(letter) <= 23:    # if the character is in the alphabet and is between a-x...
    thread = thread.replace(letter, cipher[cipher.index(letter) + 2], 1)    # replace that letter with the one two letters after it, and save

  elif letter in cipher and cipher.index(letter) > 23:   # but if the character is y or z...
    thread = thread.replace(letter, cipher[cipher.index(letter) - 24], 1)    # replace those with a and b, respectively

print(thread)
```

This yields an output of:

```
o hoti ioi hihtt tterapati it ha hand. thaty uhat aoonutets ate dot. doine it in dw hand is ineddiaient and thyt's ufw rfis rexr gs so none. ssgne srrgne.oyierpyns() gs peammkcnbcb. lmu ynnlw ml rfc spl.
```

The thing that stuck out to me is that the first letter (g) is incorrectly transposed by 8 steps. However, the second letter (f) is correctly transposed by 2 steps. The other incorrect letters appear to be transposed by different amounts. I went back and took apart my code to check if the individual parts worked:

```
print(cipher[cipher.index("g") + 2]) # this bit is functional and converts letters a-x by a shift of 2. more specifically, it does CORRECTLY convert g to i.

print(cipher[cipher.index("y") - 24]) # this is functional too and converts y and z
```

I am not sure what is wrong with this script. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I manage to decrypt your `thread` , however i used a slightly different approach . I can post it if you are really stuck.

Comment: **Hint** the formula for caesar cipher is `alphabet[ ( letter_pos + rotation ) % 26  ]`

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know the formal formula to solve a cipher of this type. This helps a lot. However, it would still be nice to know what is wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok , this is how i solved it , based on your code :

```
thread = "g fmnc wms bgblr rpylqjyrc gr zw fylb. rfyrq ufyr amknsrcpq ypc dmp. bmgle gr gl zw fylb gq glcddgagclr ylb rfyr'q ufw rfgq rcvr gq qm jmle. sqgle qrpgle.kyicrpylq() gq pcamkkclbcb. lmu ynnjw ml rfc spj."
cipher = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
thread_decrypted = ''  ## I used an empty string to append the rotated letters ##

for letter in thread:
    if letter in cipher : 
        if cipher.index(letter) <= 23 : 
            thread_decrypted += cipher[ cipher.index(letter) + 2 ]  
        else :  
            thread_decrypted += cipher[ cipher.index(letter) -24 ]  
    else : 
        thread_decrypted += letter

print(thread_decrypted)
```

A simpler, more 'pythonic' way is something like this :

```
thread = "g fmnc wms bgblr rpylqjyrc gr zw fylb. rfyrq ufyr amknsrcpq ypc dmp. bmgle gr gl zw fylb gq glcddgagclr ylb rfyr'q ufw rfgq rcvr gq qm jmle. sqgle qrpgle.kyicrpylq() gq pcamkkclbcb. lmu ynnjw ml rfc spj."
cipher = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"  
thread_decrypted = ''.join( cipher[ ( cipher.index(l) + 2 ) % 26 ] if l in cipher else l for l in thread )
print(thread_decrypted)
```

which is basically your for loop in one line ( list comprehension ) .

The problem with your code is that you use `replace()` .
Every time you iterate the original string gets mutated
( 'a' becomes 'c' , then it becomes 'e', etc ) ,
and thats why you get errors .

I hope this helps, good luck with your studies

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was under the impression that replace() would go through each letter of the thread systematically, since it's in a for loop. That's apparently not the case. So my question is: do for loops not iterate through a list or thread systematically? Is it random?

Comment: Your logic seems to be correct ( go through each letter of the `thread` and replace the first occurance ), but you missed one detail . You may loop through the letters systematically ( indexed ) , but that does not affect `replace` . Imagine you reached the 10th letter,  if `replace` finds a match on the 4th letter , it will replace the 4th letter not the 10th . Perhaps you could turn `thread` to a list , modify it's elements and then `join` it back to a string , but i don't think you can use `replace`

Comment: In short , the problem is here : `thread = thread.replace` , think about it .

Answer (score 0):

```
words = 'g fmnc wms bgblr rpylqjyrc gr zw fylb. rfyrq ufyr amknsrcpq ypc dmp. bmgle gr gl zw fylb gq glcddgagclr ylb rfyrq ufw rfgq rcvr gq qm jmle. sqgle qrpgle.kyicrpylq() gq pcamkkclbcb. lmu ynnjw ml rfc spj.'
    
table = words.maketrans('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzab')
    
print(words.translate(table))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.